# How to find the devices in the range by using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to android.I want to develop an application to find the devices in the range by using Bluetooth programmatically.If any one has idea please give some sample code to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Find The Devices in the Range by using Bluetooth programmatically.`

Yes you can do this using [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), check out below code, it will help you.

*Starting search*

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
```

*Finds a device*

```
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
    {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
       mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
  }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Broad cast receiver something like the following and add the device information

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>();    
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                HashMap<String, String> deviceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                deviceMap.put(device.getName(), device.getAddress());
                arl.add(deviceMap);

            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }


    };
```

Comment: Thanks sunil for u'r response.this code is not working please send full code.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use method startDiscovery() .

I dont have a sample code right now but you might want to have a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery%28%29

Hope it helps!