# How to discover devices within a certain distance

Tags: android, bluetooth

As explained in the following thread: 
[How to find the devices in the range by using bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464015/how-to-find-the-devices-in-the-range-by-using-bluetooth)

An android app can get a list of devices in the range (bluetooth enabled)

My question is that if there is any way to limit the discovery range to a certain radius e.g. 1 meter?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI` to get the signal strength.
Nevertheless, it won't be very accurate because it's variable.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
            System.out.println("RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm");
        }
    }
};
```

The value you obtain is in `dBm`. A **really close** device would have a rssi between around -20 dBm and -40 dBm depending of the device (built-in Bluetooth device, antenna, actual orientation of device). You can test the values you get to define an average 'dBm-range' for 1 meter.  The closer the value is to 0, the stronger the received signal has been.